# Support text content in Silverlight control?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, text

my silverlight control can support stuff being passed into it like so:

```
<MyControl>
<OtherControl/>
</MyControl>
```

But if I do this:

```
<MyControl>
THIS IS TEXT
</MyControl>
```

and attempt to run it I get an error saying:

> MyControl does not support text content. [Line: 142 Position:
>   72]

MyControl's item property should support everything as its an object, so it can support Textbox's and buttons and other controls. but if I try to pass in just raw text it doesn't work.

I know thisshould be doable, my only question is, how?

Comment: I dunno exactly but it was something like in OnApplyTemplate look if it contains a string. If it does wrap the string in a textbox and add that to the control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to derive your control from [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) as follows:

```
public class SimpleControl : ContentControl {

}
```

---

```
<local:SimpleControl>
    Some Text...
</local:SimpleControl>

<local:SimpleControl>
    <Button Content="Button" />
</local:SimpleControl>
```

Answer (score 3):

you must define a dependency property for your control that you can usinig from binding for your control.
see fllowing code:

```
public class customtextbox : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        TextBox.TextProperty.AddOwner(typeof(customtextbox));
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

and you set Text property :

```
<CT:customtextbox Text="somthing"/>  OR
<CT:customtextbox Text="{Binding  mypropertyinviewmodel}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the compiler what property of your class is to be used for content in between the tags in XAML.

Let's say the property you want to use is

```
public string Title { get; set; }
```

Above your class definition, you need to add the ContentProperty attribute like so:

```
[ContentProperty("Title")]
public class MyControl
{
    // class code
}
```

Comment: I already have a cotnentproperty for objects called Item and I can't add it more than once :-/